# Java printing a pattern for loops

Tags: java

I am starting to learn java. I have learned for loops and am trying to print this pattern, based on user input to tell us how many lines and characters the square should have.

```
-+++
+-++
++-+
+++-
```

but i can't figure out how to get two nested for loops going at once to do this. can someone please help?

Comment: Can you show the user input and your code so far?

Comment: please tell us what will the user input do or what will it be

Comment: Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the user input on which the pattern is based, or how it affects what the pattern looks like.  Is the input just one number, the size of the square? Are the dashes `-` just the diagonal of the square, and everything else is a plus `+`? Your problem statement is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to support @YassinHajaj's answer:

```
int len = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {//iterates through the rows
  for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {//iterates through the columns
    if(i == j) {
      System.out.print("-");
    }else{
      System.out.print("+");
    }
  }
  System.out.println("");//print new line after row is finished.
}
```

Comment: why 2 loops ? you can do it with one.

Comment: @StackFlowed I am doing it in two loop for sake of simplicity.

Comment: @StackFlowed If you have a one loop solution that is better, why haven't you answered the question?

Comment: @Andreas as per request -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/33289705/1085186

Comment: Yes, it can be done with one loop, no, it is not as elegant or readable.

Comment: @phflack Well, I think my one-loop answer is pretty elegant. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You just need two loops, nested and when the counter from the first one equals the counter from the second one, print `-`, otherwise print `+`.

I think the code for this is very easy to produce once you've got the idea.

Good luck with that.

Comment: This is not an answer. It can be a comment.

Comment: @StackFlowed this is an answer because it answers the question. Answer != code

Comment: This is **the** answer, I posted an example for an example implementation of this.

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine, note that no conditional statements are used here and this will work for **any number of lines and characters(ch)** and not limited to just square inputs.

```
int lines = 4;
int ch = 4;
for(int i=0;i<lines;i++) { //lines
    int ch1 = i%ch;  //mod of current line and number of characters, 
    //Above is for dynamic number of lines and characters, not just square inputs.
    for(int j=0;j<ch1; j++) {
        System.out.print("+");
    }
    System.out.print("-");
    for(int j=ch1;j<ch-1; j++) {
        System.out.print("+");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example of a way to get the pattern

It starts out with a loop to go through the rows, then loops before the "-" and after the "-" to fill in with "+"s

```
    int count = 8;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < i; a++)
            System.out.print("+");
        System.out.print("-");
        for(int b = i + 1; b < count; b++)
            System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one loop solution :

```
int len = 4;
int pos = 1;
for(int i=1;pos<len+1;i++) {
    if(i%(len+1)==0) {
        pos=pos+1;
        i=0;
        System.out.println();
    } else if(i==pos) {
        System.out.print("-");
    } else {
        System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```

Output :

```
-+++
+-++
++-+
+++-
```

Comment: That is a one loop solution but note that it doesnot make it efficient, the `ifs` slow it down.

Comment: you think if is slower that nested for loops ? BTW its else if  not just ifs

Comment: If it provides more dynamic hand to the user where it doesnot need to be limited to just a square output, then yes.

Comment: @Mr.Robot i think you are loosing track this pattern is only for square design.

Comment: Well, it depends on how the OP sees every answer. @Andreas answer seems to be legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Short, very fast, single-loop version:

```
public static void printSquare(int size) {
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    Arrays.fill(buf, '+');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buf[i] = '-';
        System.out.println(buf);
        buf[i] = '+';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.fill(char[], char)` uses a for loop (not nested at least), but this is a fairly amusing solution

Comment: @phflack Sure it's a bit different from all the other solutions here, but it does "block" printing, only calling `print` once per line, and doesn't have the overhead of strings, so it is definitely the fastest too (least work per line). Of course, for something this small, performance is immaterial (and premature), but I can accept your "amusing" label. ;-)

Comment: While probably not quite what the Q was looking for, I actually like this way a lot more.  I'm a bit surprised that printing a `char[]` works, instead of giving the usual array printing text